# Как добавить значение к названию таблицы?

Tags: python, sqlite

Работаю с БД `SQLite`, для удобства одновременно работаю с SQLiteStudio.

Как при создании таблицы `CREATE TABLE name` можно добавить любое значение из переменной для `name` (допустим, значение `a = 1`) и чтобы таблица получилась с название `name1`?

Comment: А зачем вам это понадобилось ? В 99% случаев когда это кажется нужным, это говорит о неправильном проектировании БД. Потом с такими таблицами работать будет мучительно больно

Comment: Каково происхождение этого `name1` подразумевается?

Comment: @mkkik, чтобы таблица называлась name1. Допустим я пишу, создай таблицу тест, создаёт таблицу с названием теста.

Comment: Не очень понятно, куда вы пишете. И почему в таком случае нельзя сразу явно указать имя таблицы.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно сформировать запрос динамически.

Например, формируете в переменной имя и потом подставляете в текст запроса.

P.S. Колом помочь не могу, т.к. сейчас под рукой нет Python.

Comment: `'name%s' % a` или `'name{}'.format(a)`

Answer (score 1):

Можешь попробовать использовать `string.replace`.

```
a = 1
b = 'name' + str(a)
query  = ('CREATE TABLE name').replace('name', b)
print(query)
```